# Execute code on model creation in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to execute some code in a Django model when it is first created. After that whenever it is saved I want to execute some other code. The second task can be easily done by overriding the save() method.
How can I do the first task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)' [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save):

```
# models.py

from django.db.models import signals

class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

def my_model_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    """Argument explanation:

       sender - The model class. (MyModel)
       instance - The actual instance being saved.
       created - Boolean; True if a new record was created.

       *args, **kwargs - Capture the unneeded `raw` and `using`(1.3) arguments.
    """
    if created:
        # your code goes here


# django 1.3+
from django.dispatch import dispatcher
dispatcher.connect(my_model_post_save, signal=signals.post_save, sender=MyModel)

# django <1.3
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
post_save.connect(my_model_post_save, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: I tried this but was getting an error. Turned out I am using Django version (1, 1, 1, 'final', 0) and this works only for Django 1.3 and above. I will try to upgrade but do you know any other method? Thanks!

Comment: @Rohit: What was the error in 1.1.1?  These signals existed in 1.1.1, the setup just may be a little different, or I have a typo.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal: I glanced at the old docs and updated the bottom of my example of what should work for 1.1.1.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'`. Then I tried using the receiver decorator(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-specific-signals) but I got `ImportError: cannot import name receiver`

Comment: Yeah, setting up the signals through the dispatcher module was added in 1.3.  You need to connect using the `signals.post_save.connect` shown at the bottom.

Answer (score 38):

Extending [sdolan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186868/sdolan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8170763/909579) by using `receiver` decorator:

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver

class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=MyModel)
def execute_after_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # code
```

Comment: This is what works now with django 1.10, rather than the accepted answer which was presumably correct for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

[field.default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default)

*The default value for the field. This can be a value or a **callable** object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is created.*

So, we can use any field callable to do what we want on creation, huh? ;-)