# How to send email with django "Rest Framwork"?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using small Rest api project
and it works fantastic.

But somehow i have to make send email function in there.

so i added email config in settings.py like that

// settings.py

```
# SMTP Mail service with decouple
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EM_ACCOUNT')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EM_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

//views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from consult.models import Consult
from consult.serializers import ConsultSerializer
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


class ConsultViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Consult.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ConsultSerializer


def send_email(request):
    email = EmailMessage(
        'Title',
        (ConsultSerializer.name, ConsultSerializer.email, ConsultSerializer.phone),
        'my-email',
        ['my-receive-email']
    )
    email.attach_file(ConsultSerializer.file)
    email.send()
```

// models.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Consult(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    describe = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Consult'
```

// serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Consult


class ConsultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Consult
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'position', 'group', 'email', 'phone', 'describe', 'file', 'create_date')
```

Yup. that is all of my codes.
And i setted send_mail function in views.

Honestly I want automatic send mail function 
when the consult data in my DB. but I can find only normal django explanation.

Can you help me set a automatic send mail function when data created??

Comment: What you mean by `automatic send mail function` ?

Comment: @JPG I meant i want that function will work when new data come, work with create DB

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170704/execute-code-on-model-creation-in-django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute code on model creation in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170704/execute-code-on-model-creation-in-django)

Comment: could you provide the urls.py....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method-1** : override the **`create()`** method of **ConsultViewSet**

```
def send_email():
    email = EmailMessage(
        'Title',
        (ConsultSerializer.name, ConsultSerializer.email, ConsultSerializer.phone),
        'my-email',
        ['my-receive-email']
    )
    email.attach_file(ConsultSerializer.file)
    email.send()


class ConsultViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Consult.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ConsultSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ConsultViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        send_email()  # sending mail
        return response
```

Comment: i've got an error // AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'create'

Comment: I forgot to add `self` in that statement. Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) I was wondering if the approach `ConsultSerializer.name` is still working? I used the solution in a similar way but wasn't able to access the Serializer objects, like similar to `ConsultSerializer.name`

Comment: type object 'ConsultSerializer' has no attribute 'name'  i am getting this error can any one help on this

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it's better practice to use [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) instead of overriding the `create()` method. As an example, you can use below code in your models.py file:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.CONSULT_MODEL)
def send_mail_on_create(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        send_email() # call send mail function
```

What this does is that it receives a signal when an instance of your model is created and does whatever thing you want it to. you can also change the `post_save` to `pre_save` and/or other available default signals, or even define your own signal and send it from inside the model `create()` function.

Comment: Wondering why this would be better practice? Seems that it would increase system complexity by adding more interfaces, while decreasing readability by pulling the `send_mail` task away from where it would essentially be created, correct? I mean, it is probably negligible when it comes to optimization but then readability would become most important, no?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidAlford , I totally understand what you're saying, and I have also thought about it. The thing is if You do the error handling well and consider all exceptions that might happen in the create method, then sending email inside that function would be fine. but wouldn't it also be easier to debug if any exceptions occur inside these two tasks, if they are implemented in a hierarchical order? as in, when the account is created > do the email jobs. I guess I shouldn't have used the term better practice, since it's easier for me and might not be more readable to others.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Only asked to see a different point of view and the reasons as to why. Will consider it more in future projects.